# How to make an image in a div appear using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, timed

How do I make an image in a div fade in or pop up after a a certain amount of seconds using Javascript? I have researched this but none of the answers on here seem to apply to me.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like you want to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'}, 5000)
</script>
<div>
    <div id='image' style='display:none'>
        Here should be your image
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/wUb8T/